# Please explain why the loop is executing for 11 times

Tags: c, printf, logical-operators

```c
#include<stdio.h>
    
int main() {
    int loop=10;
    while(printf("Hello ") && loop--);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: .Just change the line `while(printf("Hello ") && loop--);` to `while(printf("Hello ") && loop--) { printf(" %d", loop);}` to see what is going on

Answer (score 4):

The loop actually only executes 10 times -- the *test* executes 11 times.  Since the loop body itself is empty (the printf is part of the test), you don't notice that it is only executing 10 times.

It is the nature of top-checked loops that for a loop of n iterations, the test will be evaluated n+1 times -- it gets evaluated before the loop ever executes (so it might execute zero times), and after every execution.

Comment: You may try --loop instead of loop-- to get it to loop 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

The start of the `while()` hinges partly on the value of the loop value.  If it starts at 10 and each `while()` decrements by 1, then it will loop 11 times to reach `loop==0`.

All is good until loop == -1, which turns into a false.

The `while()` function can be read like `while(loop > -1, then true)...otherwise false`.

Comment: This answer is confusing at best. When `loop==0` (not `loop==-1`) the conditional evaluates to false, even though it will be decremented afterward (and be -1 after the loop).

Answer (score 0):

> explain why the loop is executing for 11 times

The `while` loop body executed 10 times.

```
int main() {
    int loop=10;
    while(printf("Hello ") && loop--){
      printf("Body\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The test condition `printf("Hello ") && loop--` executed 11 times.  The last time, it was false.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the printf() statement is inside the while *condition*. When `loop == 0`, the condition still has to be executed and see that the result of `(printf() && loop--)` is false, in which case the while loop is terminated.

Additionally, logical conditions are evaluated until they are definitely `true` or definitely `false`. A logical AND operation can definitely be `false` when either of its operands are `false`. If you were to swap the positions of the operands, you'd only print "Hello " 10 times as opposed to 11.

```
int loop = 10;
while (loop-- && printf("Hello "));
```

`loop--` would evaluate to `false` before the `printf("Hello ")` statement is reached when `loop == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
int loop=10;
while(printf("Hello ") && loop--){
printf("Body\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

As the while condition is associated with a printf() statement, the loop is executed for 10 times and during the execution of 11th iteration, thought the condition is false, printf("Hello") gets executed for one more time.

However, it is clear that while loop got executed only for 10 times.

Thanks to all who responded to the question.